# HTML CSS make columns of text rows (br)

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a HTML setup of the following:

```
<p class="vcard contact" role="contentinfo">
 <a class="org url organization-name" href="url" title="organization">organization</a><br>
 <span class="fn">name</span><br>
 <a class="tel" href="tel:tel">tel</a><br>
 <a class="email" href="mailto:email">email</a>
</p>
```

What CSS would I apply to make this columned? Organization and name on the left and tel and email on the right for example.

I could change the HTML, but I want it to be modular and keep HTML and CSS strictly separated.

Comment: Maybe mark it up as an unordered list and float the list elements? Pure CSS columns are tricky at the moment, depending on what you need/want to support.

Comment: Maybe like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/twwQf/)?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzucC/2/)

```
.vcard
{
    position:relative;
}

.organization-name
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.fn
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
}

.tel
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
}

.email
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean how to make columns? You could change the order a little and make all elements blocks, then float them so each element inside vcard takes up 50% width.

Removing the line breaks would also make it easier to manipulate with css

```
.vcard a, .vcard .fn {
    display : block;
    float : left;
    width : 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mickadoo/zSytv/

Comment: I guess changing the order is unavoidable. Gah, if only design would be really left to CSS only...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DzucC/4/

```
.col1 { float:left; } .col2 {  float:left;
    margin-left:15px; }

<div>
    <div class="vcard contact col1" role="contentinfo">
     <a class="org url organization-name" href="url" title="organization">organization</a>  <br>
     <span class="fn">name</span><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <a class="tel" href="tel:tel">     tel</a><br>
        <a class="email" href="mailto:email">email</a>
    </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<table>`,`<td>`,`<tbody>`,`<thead>` and more.
Read: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp